# Check for error on process stop

Tags: batch-file, service, restart, errorlevel

I want to restart a service, and if I get error level 5 I want to reboot the machine. but when I try it just exits the script.

```
NET STOP TeamViewer9 && NET START TeamViewer9

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1(
    ECHO proceed to restart...
    PAUSE
    SHUTDOWN /F /R /T 30
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing with a value with an opening parenthesis in it;

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1(
```

is the same as

```
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1("
```

and that's not what you want.  Just insert a space before the ( so it is related to the IF statement and not the 1) :

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
```

Batch language is a bit easy to fool; it really should have complained about a missing left parenthesis rather than skipping the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

you need space before openning bracket:

```
NET STOP TeamViewer9 && NET START TeamViewer9

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==5 (
    ECHO proceed to restart...
    PAUSE
    SHUTDOWN /F /R /T 30
)
```